# How to disable one row of DevExpress XtraGrid in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using DevExpress XtraGrid in c#.NET application. I want to disable or set readonly property to  particular row of XtraGrid .
Please Help.

Comment: DevExpress has a pretty good support service. I think it's better to try to search/ask there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `GridView.ShowingEditor` event and set `e.Cancel = true`

Comment: after binding GridView  i want to disable 1 row of GridView .Is it possible by using this.?

Comment: @Vyas: the `GridView.ShowingEditor` event is raised when the user clicks within cell. you can check in the event handler if the cell is in a disabled row and if it is set `e.Cancel = true` so that the editor will not be shown.